# Why are block variables optional?

Tags: ruby, block, optional-parameters

Non-block variables are obligatory:

```
def foo arg; end
foo # => ArgumentError
```

In order to allow optional arguments, a default value has to be supplied:

```
def foo arg = nil; end
foo # => nil
```

But block variables are optional:

```
def foo &block; end
foo # => nil
```

Without a default value, an absent block variable is assigned `nil`, and in fact, block variables cannot take default values:

```
def foo &block = ->{puts :foo}; end
# => syntax error
```

On the contrary, a method can take an extra block that is not required in the definition:

```
def foo; end
foo{puts :foo} # => nil
```

What is the advantage of block variables being designed like this as opposed to non-block variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There wouldn't be much point throwing an error when no block is given, since any method that uses either `yield` or `block.call` will throw an error anyway if there is no block.
There also wouldn't be much point supplying a default block, since the default code to be executed can just be written into the method itself (which would be a lot neater than writing it inline with the arguments).